# How do you make SignalR work with RequireJS?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, signalr

When using SignalR with hubs, you need to include a script with a src of "/signalr/hubs" - i.e. with no .js extension. When I try to use this with RequireJS, it insists on adding the '.js' extension which means that hub proxy is never loaded.

Any ideas how to stop it doing that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answering my own question for benefit of others: I found a 'noext' plugin for RequireJS [here](https://gist.github.com/1057913) which solves issue.

As stated on that page, this relates to [Issue 18](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/issues/18) of RequireJS

Comment: perfect--was just trying this today.  Thanks for posting the answer.  Upvoted both :)

Comment: I don't think you even need the plugin. All it does it add a querystring. You can do that yourself. `~/signalr/hubs?t=1` is what I did and it worked fine.